# Which platform should I adopt for web and mobile development?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, ide, flash-builder

I have used Flash Builder and previously Flash for at least the past 15 years and am looking at the' writing on the wall' concerning the demise of Flash based software. I find ActionScript3 to be a powerful and elegant programming language and am hesitant to move towards what I perceive html5 to be because it appears that the underlying programming language is like taking a step back in time. It does not appear to be fully object oriented and I have yet to see a sophisticated IDE for it. Also, I have not seen an html5 equivalent of the Flash media server to capture and deliver video.
I'm not a professional developer, I'm a college professor who does a lot of design and development work and I need a platform that will be around for a while, that is technologically advanced, and that will continue to evolve. I've worked with xCode, but am concerned that it it too limited to IOS. I'd like to hear from others who can guide me in my decision making.

Comment: This question provokes debates and has a high potential of being closed quickly.

Comment: Look into Visual Studio Web Express - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web#product-express-web.

Answer (score 1):

For web-based stuff, in your case, I'd definitely say to stick it out with AS3 until things become more absolute.  Flash has issues that HTML5 doesn't, but the opposite is also true.  Flash's issues are more permanent and/or something that Adobe just doesn't care about like it should, but HTML5, from what I understand, is still "growing up" and is not quite mature yet.  Flash isn't dead yet, it's still well-established, and you're already really used to using it.  So I'd say stick with that for right now, and change later when it's a better time to do so.